# Removing newline character

Tags: encryption, character, newline

So currently I've had a problem for the past few hours. I've looked through many stack overflow posts and have tried every suggestion. What my problem is, is I have a program that grabs words from a text file and gives them an MD5 encryption.

```
            fileName = raw_input("> ")
            if fileName.endswith(".txt") or fileName.endswith(".lst"):
                    fopen = open(fileName, 'r')
            else:
                    fileName = fileName + ".txt"
                    fopen = open(fileName, 'r')

            m = hashlib.md5()

            for line in fopen:
                    sleep(1)
                    m.update(line)
                    encHash = m.hexdigest()
                    hashed = [line, encHash]
                    new_line = []
                    for elem in hashed:
                            new_line.extend(elem.strip('\n').split(' '))
                    searchfile = open("Passwords.txt").read()

                    if line in searchfile:
                            print ""
                    else:
                            fopen = open("Passwords.txt", 'a')
                            fopen.write(str(hashed))
                            fopen.write("\n")
                            fopen.close
                            print str(new_line)
```

Now as you can see, I've already dealt with the new line characters being outputted. But the encrypted version still has the \n at the end. So instead of "12345" being encrypted "12345\n" is.

[image]

[image]

I've tried rstrip(), and strip(). But it doesn't seem to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

**EDIT**
I don't know what I did, I just re-wrote the code and its working fine! Thanks for all the suggestions.

```
        elif choice == "2":
            os.system('clear')
            fileName = raw_input('Filename: ')
            fopen = open(fileName, 'rb')

            for line in fopen:
                    line = line.rstrip('\n')
                    enc = hashlib.md5()
                    enc.update(line)
                    encHash = enc.hexdigest()
                    hashed = {line:encHash}
                    fwrite = open('Password.txt', 'a')
                    hashed = str(hashed)
                    data = open("Password.txt").read()
                    if hashed in data:
                            print hashed
                    else:
                            fwrite.write(hashed)
                            fwrite.write("\n")
                            fwrite.close
                            print hashed
```

Comment: Is this on a Windows machine (Which has "\r\n" line endings)? In any case, consider using `os.linesep` instead of "\n" unless you know you are expecting exactly that as the line ending.

Comment: I don't think you entirely know what the problem is. Its not writing new lines, its reading new lines. When reading from a file its adding '\n' and I can't remove it.

Comment: Of course I don't know what the entire problem is, I have no access to the needed information to answer the problem. You do. Reading from a file does not change the content of it. in `open("Passwords.txt").read()` you read the raw bytes, and in `open(fileName, 'r')` you iterate the lines. Neither adds newlines. Check your source file for newlines in a hex editor if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Python but it sounds like it could be related to the way you're opening the file.

Try using  open(fileName, 'rb') instead of  open(fileName, 'r').

This link describes the \r\n \n diffs.  Opening a file up as binary will convert the newline character to newline sequence respective of the system you are running the code on.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Hello IntStarFoo, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work sadly.

Comment: I am new to the Stack Exchange model of question answering.  My experience thus far has been such that the tolerance for incorrect interaction between the asker and the askee is ZERO.  I appreciate you awarding me some ... point things...  for giving you some advice on things to try.  But I feel it is in our best interest to play by the rules outlined and enforced by the established users of this website.  I hearby prepare to bequeath them back to you and remove my ... text.  From the question.  I also give you the badge of patience and the badge of humor.

Comment: After further investigation, I have decided the best way to fix this is to ask you to post the answer to the question.  Maybe a quick example of the thing that fixed it?  Maybe simply restating your edit.  I will be happy to upvote your answer (at the discretion of the community of course).